# Expected value suggested by simulation

Tags: probability, expected-value, simulation

If $X$ is random variable giving the first $n$ value such as $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is multiple of $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$, where $X_i$ are independent variables with uniform distributions on $\{1,\cdots,k\}$. The following simulation let think that the expected value of $X$ is $m$, but I can't prove it in general case.

```
import random

def D(k):
    return random.randint(1,k)

def X(m,k):
    s = D(k)
    n = 1
    while not s%m == 0:
        s = s+D(k)
        n = n+1
    return n
```

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What is $X$?

Comment: @lulu I think that e.g. $X=3$ iff $X_1$ and $X_1+X_2$ are not multiples of $m$ and $X_1+X_2+X_3$ is a multiple of $m$. That gives indeed $\mathbb EX=m$.

Comment: @lulu My first comment should maybe have been accompanied with "under suitable conditions". Personally I had a look at a (suitable) example and discovered that $\mathbb EX=\frac1{m}+\frac{m-1}{m}(1+\mathbb EX)$ in that case. Here $\frac1{m}$ is the probability that $X_1$ is a multiple of $m$ but for that it is needed that $m\leq k$.

Comment: The result seems correct even if $m > k$ and the case $k=1$ is obvious. But in general case ...

Comment: @MB4E  Yes, you are right, but I can't see why.  I've checked many cases exactly now and it always works out.  It is not true that you always expect it to take $m$ tries from whatever state you start in, but it appears to be true if you start from $0$.    Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume $k \geq 2$ without losing the generality. Let $Y = (Y_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be the stochastic process defined by

$$ Y_n = (X_1 + \cdots + X_n) \text{ mod } m.$$

Then $Y$ is an aperiodic and irreducible Markov chain on the state space $\mathcal{S} = \{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$. In particular, $Y$ has a unique stationary measure $\pi = (\pi_i)_{i\in\mathcal{S}}$. Then it is easy to check that

$$ \pi_i = \frac{1}{m}, \qquad i \in \mathcal{S} $$

using the definition of $Y$.

Also, if $m_i$ denotes the expected return time to state $i \in \mathcal{S}$, then the general theory of Markov chain tells that $m_i = 1/\pi_i = m $. Since the answer to OP's question corresponds to $m_0$, the expected return time to $0$, we are done.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which therefore confirms the result, even if I will have to study the Markov chains to understand. Does the uniform distribution of $X_i$ matter here ?

Comment: @MB4E, No problem. As for your question, the result still holds as long as the resulting chain $Y$ is aperiodic and irreducible. A sufficient condition is that the support of $X_i \text{ mod } m$ contains a pair of coprime numbers.

Comment: Is the aperiodic condition needed since the state space is finite ?